# Обособление согласованных определений

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, стоит ли в данном предложении обособлять прилагательное с зависимым словом? Или здесь "слово" тесно связано с последующей конструкцией?

*Но попадаются слова (?) превосходные по своей выразительности, например старинное, до сих пор бытующее в этих областях слово "окоём" - горизонт.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ударение во фразе может падать как на "слова", так и на "превосходные", поэтому появляются сомнения в обособлении/необособлении. Но определяемое слово самодостаточно, то есть без определения смысл предложения не теряется, запятая возможна и не противоречит правилам. Хотя, поразмыслив, всё же думаю, что в данном случае не стоит разделять запятой эту связку — так предложение будет выглядеть логичней.

[**Обособление согласованных определений**](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/714-233_obosoblenie_soglasovannyh_opredelenii.html)

> Не обособляются распространённые и однородные одиночные определения, стоящие после существительного, если существительное нуждается в определении, если без этого определения высказывание не имеет законченного смысла. В устной речи именно на эти определения падает логическое ударение, а пауза между определяемым словом и определением отсутствует. Например: *Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука в стороне **глухой и отдалённой*** (Пушкин). *Где-то на этом свете есть жизнь **чистая, изящная, поэтическая*** (Чехов).

Answer (score 2):

***Обособление не требуется, поскольку распространённое согласованное определение "превосходные по своей выразительности" тесно примыкает к определяемому существительному, которое нуждается в определении: оно необходимо для создания полного по смыслу, законченного высказывания.***

Необходимы не просто *слова*, а *слова превосходные по своей выразительности*.